# Work Queue - Updating Narrative(Status - Text) in Work Queue Item

Tags: automation, blueprism, rpa

Working on sample process work queue in Blue Prism. I am successfully able to process work queue items. However, I am not able to update queue items.
I am using calc stage where I am setting value as [RetrievedData.Status]  =  "Test", after this calling Set Data action (Passing RetrievedData collection and Item ID). When retrieving an item as Get-Item I am not able to see the updated value "Test" in Status column.

Can anybody please help.

Please see the attached screenshot][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3Ewg.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am using calc stage where I am setting value as [RetrievedData.Status] = "Test"

No, you are currently testing whether `[RetrievedData.Status]` is equal to `"Test"` (and storing True/False to the data item `Result`). To set `[RetrievedData.Status]` to `"Test"`, you need to use it like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

are you using that specific item id for which you have updated data in 2nd get item? if not then 2nd get item will pick a new item from queue not the same item. Instead of using get item 2nd time you can use get item data action to verify the updated data

Comment: Thanks will check and let you know. By the way, I was able to achieve this with Collection Manipulation VBO, it is adding field to collection at runtime.